# How do i format this project

Tags: php, mysql

I have a several tables that make up a schedule.  I am using PHP and MySQL with Linux.  The code is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){    
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>View All Employees</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"><br><br><br>
<p>xxxxxxxxxx</p></div>
<div id="side"><?php
include ('includes/side.php');
?>
</div>
<div id="main">
<center><h3><b>Past Schedules</b></h3></center>
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx'); 
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Job Date</th><th>Report</th><th>Start</th><th>Customer</th><th>Crew</th>    <th>Equipment</th><th>Description</th><th>Job Notes</th>';
echo '</tr>';


$result = $db->query("SELECT
            `ScheduledJob`.`ScheduledJobID`,
            `ScheduledJob`.`JobDate`,
            `ScheduledJob`.`ReportTime`,
            `ScheduledJob`.`StartTime`,
            `ScheduledJob`.`CustomerID`,
            `Customer`.`Name` AS `CustomerName`,
            `ScheduledEmployee`.`EmployeeID`,
            CAST(NULL AS SIGNED INTEGER) AS `EquipmentID`,
            `ScheduledJob`.`JobDescription`,
            CONCAT(`Employee`.`FirstName`, ' ', `Employee`.`LastName`) AS   `EmployeeName`,
                '' AS `EquipmentNumber`
FROM
            (`ScheduledJob` INNER JOIN
            `Customer` ON `ScheduledJob`.`CustomerID`=`Customer`.`CustomerID`) LEFT JOIN
            (`ScheduledEmployee` INNER JOIN
            `Employee` ON `ScheduledEmployee`.`EmployeeID`=`Employee`.`EmployeeID`) ON   `ScheduledJob`.`ScheduledJobID`=`ScheduledEmployee`.`ScheduledJobID`
UNION
SELECT
            `ScheduledJob`.`ScheduledJobID`,
            `ScheduledJob`.`JobDate`,
            `ScheduledJob`.`ReportTime`,
            `ScheduledJob`.`StartTime`,
            `ScheduledJob`.`CustomerID`,
            `Customer`.`Name` AS `CustomerName`,
            CAST(NULL AS SIGNED INTEGER) AS `EmployeeID`,
            `ScheduledEquipment`.`EquipmentID`,
            `ScheduledJob`.`JobDescription`,
            '' AS `EmployeeName`,
            `Equipment`.`Number` AS `EquipmentNumber`
FROM
            (`ScheduledJob` INNER JOIN
            `Customer` ON `ScheduledJob`.`CustomerID`=`Customer`.`CustomerID`) LEFT JOIN
            (`ScheduledEquipment` INNER JOIN
            `Equipment` ON `ScheduledEquipment`.`EquipmentID`=`Equipment`.`EquipmentID`)     ON `ScheduledJob`.`ScheduledJobID`=`ScheduledEquipment`.`ScheduledJobID`;");
while($job = $result->fetch_object()){ 
echo '<tr>';    
echo '<td>',$job->JobDate,'</td>';
echo '<td>',$job->ReportTime,'</td>';
echo '<td>',$job->StartTime,'</td>';
echo '<td>',$job->CustomerName,'</td>';
echo '<td>',$job->EmployeeName,'</td>';
echo '<td>',$job->EquipmentNumber,'</td>';
echo '<td>',$job->JobDescription,'</td>';
echo '<td>',$job->JobNotes,'</td>';     
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
<?php
} else {
header("location:index.php");
}
?></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is currently like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Date    Report      Start       Customer        Crew              Equipment Description             Job Notes
 2014-02-13 07:00:00    08:00:00    Spruence Genco  Steven Gray                   This is just a sample 
 2014-02-13 07:00:00    08:00:00    Spruence Genco  Phil Dunfy                  This is just a sample   
 2014-02-13 07:00:00    08:00:00    Spruence Genco  Donald Duck                 This is just a sample   
 2014-02-13 07:00:00    08:00:00    Spruence Genco                   5234       This is just a sample   
 2014-02-13 07:00:00    08:00:00    Spruence Genco                   3758       This is just a sample
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     ----------------------------
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -----------------------------
Job Date    Report      Start       Customer        Crew                Equipment   Description             Job Notes
2014-02-13  07:00:00    08:00:00    Spruence Genco  Steven Gray     5234            This is just a sample   
                                                    Phil Dunfy      3758            
                                                     Donald Duck
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can i do this.  I only want the date, report, start, customer, description, and notes to only show up once...and list all the crew
and equipment.

Please help me...

Thanks a lot.....

Comment: simple: keep track of what was output in any row. when you reach the next row, if the value in the "next" row matches what was in the "previous" row, don't output it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...but how do i do that?

Comment: Sorry, but that's basic php: set some variables, use some `if()` checks... We're here to help, not here to teach you the basics.

Comment: i would not ask here if i new how to do...lol

Comment: Don't worry, you will down voted so you will too won't be able to ask any question, stack.... do it too man :P lolz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the complete data in first row you can do this:

```
    $i = 0;
        while($job = $result->fetch_object()){ 

    if( $i == 0 ) {
        echo '<tr>';    
        echo '<td>' . $job->JobDate .'</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $job->ReportTime.'</td>';
        echo '<td>' .$job->StartTime.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$job->CustomerName.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$job->EmployeeName.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$job->EquipmentNumber.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$job->JobDescription.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$job->JobNotes.'</td>';     
        echo '</tr>';

    } else {
            echo '<tr>';    
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td>' . $job->EmployeeName . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $job->EquipmentNumber .'</td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '<td></td>';     
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $i++;
        }
```

Comment: That works great..everything is as it should be...but the equipment numbers do no print out at all.....

Comment: You can add any column which you want in else condition. I have add `$job->EquipmentNumber` this as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot....i tried your most recent revision...but the equipent numbers print under everything else...not in line like they should...but on the bottom of everything

Comment: B/c your other columns are empty, you can can format the table via css.

Comment: your a genius...i really really appreciate it...i have been racking my brain trying to figure this out